# How to use google to search for strings to check plagiarism?

Tags: javascript, php, google-search

I have a website where users post articles and my goal is to find if their articles are copied or not from another sources.

Is there an API from google (I found something yet I don't know if it was what I was looking for https://developers.google.com/custom-search/) to find the string I want and then give me the results?

Example of what I need:

***Article text: "Once on a time there was a little girl with a big house..."***

Then I would look on google if that text exists on any website and give me the percentage of what was found.

The result would be something like this:

***Text found: "Once on a time there was a little girl" (80%)***

***Website: www.examplestory.com/story/whatever***

I can do it using php or javacript since I know those two languages.

I've been looking for solutions and I think that this is what I need: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview

Comment: Google doesn't provide an API for detecting plagiarism. However, you can try [CopyScape](http://www.copyscape.com/api-guide.php) -- it's not free, but has all the features you probably want.

Comment: Thanks but I've already searched for tools similar to that one. I don't want to pay since if they have done that, I can do it too. Of course it will not work as good as their tools, but I want something simple.

Comment: This sounds like a really really bad solution.  There's plenty of English language phrases that are generic enough to trigger hits, it doesn't handle cases where external sources have been quoted but properly referenced, and even if nobody cribbed from the web, how do you know they didn't crib from each other?  There's software designed explicitly for detecting plagiarism, you should probably be using that instead.

Comment: Since the website is growing, and the number of articles too, I would spend lots of money if I use those tools. Plus, there is people who copy the entire articles from another pages, if I find little sentences, it does not matter for me. I just want to find big pieces of text.